# MySql- convert empty string to null

Tags: mysql

I have wrote a query in my **php** method to update the specific filed that has an empty string `''` to be set to `NULL`..

```
UPDATE user SET context=NULL WHERE context=''
```

or

```
UPDATE user SET context=NULL WHERE context=""
```

When this method is executed successfully, it still does not update the table fields with empty string to null. What can be the issue?

Tried:

```
UPDATE user SET context = NULL WHERE length(trim(context)) = 0
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? Does `SELECT * FROM user WHERE context=''` return rows?

Comment: context may not be equal to `''`. context may be `' '` or `'  '` or longer. You could try `update user set context = NULL where length(trim(context)) = 0`.

Comment: I updated my post as I tried your solution but still no luck. '' still remains in context field. @zedfoxus

Comment: If the column does not allow NULL then it will set it to the default value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update column with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870540/how-to-update-column-with-null-value)

Comment: Column allows null, but this command is needed if there is maybe some leftovers of empty string instead of null.. @AndrewMorton

Comment: Actually you are right SELECT * FROM user WHERE context='' does not return any row. I see it in the database, how is this possible? @AndrewMorton

Comment: «'' still remains in context field» - How do you know that? It's possible that your check is flawed. As already noted, white spaces are invisible.

Comment: That means that the update probably succeeded. You are simply not looking for the right data: you don't have empty strings, you have something else.

Comment: I do not have any other database. Context field has '' which I inputed myself. I have refreshed the table and they are still there after running an update. :/  It is a longtext field.. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I think you were missing the `sql_safe_updates = 0` part:

`$this->addSql("set sql_safe_updates = 0");`
`$this->addSql("UPDATE user SET context = if(TRIM(context)="",NULL,context");`
`$this->addSql("set sql_safe_updates = 1");`

Comment: Isn't this just a very convoluted alternative to `UPDATE user SET context = NULL WHERE TRIM(context) = ""`?